# How to dynamically signal to Rust compiler that a given variable is non-zero?

Tags: rust

I'd like to try to eliminate bounds checking on code generated by Rust. I have variables that are rarely zero and my code paths ensure they do not run into trouble. But because they can be, I cannot use `NonZeroU64`. When I am sure they are non-zero, how can I signal this to the compiler?

For example, if I have the [following function](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=ebdd2e76b5e4ddd7e515cb49be3995f2), I know it will be non-zero. Can I tell the compiler this or do I have to have the unnecessary check?

```
pub fn f(n:u64) -> u32 {
    n.trailing_zeros()
}
```

I can wrap the number in `NonZeroU64` when I am sure, but then I've already incurred the check, which defeats the purpose ...

Comment: You can use [`NonZeroU64::new_unchecked`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/num/struct.NonZeroU8.html#method.new_unchecked), though this will require the use of an `unsafe` block.

Comment: Make sure the optimizer doesn't realize they're non-zero before trying to optimize.

Answer (score 0):

Redundant checks within a single function body can usually be optimized out. So you just need convert the number to NonZeroU64 before calling `trailing_zeros()`, and rely on the compiler to optimize the bound checks.

```rust
use std::num::NonZeroU64;

pub fn g(n: NonZeroU64) -> u32 {
    n.trailing_zeros()
}

pub fn other_fun(n: u64) -> u32 {
    if n != 0 {
        println!("Do something with non-zero!");
        let n = NonZeroU64::new(n).unwrap();
        g(n)
    } else {
        42
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `if n != 0` makes sure n cannot be zero within the block, and compiler is smart enough to remove the `unwrap` call, making `NonZeroU64::new(n).unwrap()` an zero-cost operation. You can check the asm to verify that.

Answer (score -1):

[core::intrinsics::assume](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/intrinsics/fn.assume.html)

> Informs the optimizer that a condition is always true. If the
> condition is false, the behavior is undefined.
>
> No code is generated for this intrinsic, but the optimizer will try to
> preserve it (and its condition) between passes, which may interfere
> with optimization of surrounding code and reduce performance. It
> should not be used if the invariant can be discovered by the optimizer
> on its own, or if it does not enable any significant optimizations.
>
> This intrinsic does not have a stable counterpart.

Comment: @kmdreko I made it clear that it is better to use a bounds check anyway. But that was not the question of OP. The question is how to tell the compiler to avoid the bounds check and I answered it.